# In R how to add a new column of label that specifies a groupd of people?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

This data is extracted from hospital dataset, each a row is an entry of a patient at a different time, there should be multiple observations for each patient, since they come to the hosiptal several times. Like what I extracted here, there are 8 observations for patient with id 12c55eb78ef60, and 11 observations for patient with id 12e8597e4ec2a.
I have done the cleaning progress to extract those whose first entry has ckd0 ==1, which means they are at stage 0.

What i want to do is to check whether the stage of disease for the patient changes through his or her several dropbys to the hospital.
Here, if in the last observation of a patient, the "ckd0" attribute is 0, it means he progressed to higher stage, and should be labelled as 1.
If the in the last observation of a patient, the "ckd0" attribute is 1, it means he is still at stage 0, and should be labelled as 0.

I want to add such label(add a new column to the original dataframe) to each obervation of the patient. I guess it should be accomplished by a loop, but my code doesn't work. :(

[image]

x=unique(personal_id)
label = vector(mode = "numeric",length = 0)

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  temp=subset(mydata_1[which(mydata_1$personal_id==x[i]),])
  k=numeric(length(temp))
  b=order(temp$report_time)[length(temp$report_time)]

  if (temp$ckd0[b] == 0){
    k[]=1
  }
  label=c(label,k)
}

nonckd <- cbind(mydata_1,label)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify your code as little as possible.  The original problem was a little different from what I encountered.  When I ran your code, it said that the number of rows didn't match up.  This was caused by creating the `vector` `k` as such: `k < numeric(length(temp))`.  In R, the `length` of a `data.frame` is how many *columns* it has, not rows.  Replacing this with `nrow(temp)` produces the desired output.  Aside from this, I added some comments for clarification, and cleaned the code up a little.  Please let me know of any issues with the below code.

```
# sample data.frame as described

mydata_1 <- data.frame(
  personal_id = rep(c(1:10), 2),
  report_time = 1:20,
  ckd0 = sample(1:100 %% 2, 20)
  )

# variables

x <- unique(mydata_1$personal_id)
label <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  # extract a subset of the data.frame

  temp <- mydata_1[which(mydata_1$personal_id == x[i]), ]

  # create a vector initialized with 0s
  # and get last report index

  k <- numeric(nrow(temp))
  b <- order(temp$report_time)[length(temp$report_time)]

  # change 0s to 1s

  if (temp$ckd0[b] == 0) k[] <- 1

  label <- c(label, k)
}

nonckd <- cbind(mydata_1, label)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But the code still doesn't work:Error in if (temp$ckd0[b] == 0) k[] <- 1 : argument is of length zero
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)                                                                                                            I think I need to further explain the data :)        see above, i will edit my original question. Thanks again!

Comment: Would an alternate solution work, or would you like an explanation of the error?  I will try and write an alternate solution, if that will help.

Comment: I added a solution above.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Sorry for the confusion.